# Transistor Two Way Switch

Tags: transistors, switches, h-bridge

I am trying to connect the 47 ohm line from the 555 timer (refer to first picture) to either A1 to turn the motors forward or A2 to reverse the motors. Problem is I don't know how to, with two inputs, have 3 states. Power to A1, A2, or neither. The provided diagram I have tried works if I have 0 resistance on the io pin and doesn't work if I have any resistance but will short it.

[image: Diagram]

[image: Transistor Examples]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use 2 binary inputs (presumably on/off & forward/reverse), or 2 binary input *states* (hi/lo) to control your forward/off/reverse tri-state output?

Comment: yes exactly to control the h-bridge

Comment: exactly which one?

Comment: This h-bridge (basically trying to recreate the dual rocker switch in the picture but with transistors):  http://imgur.com/JN7SWai

Comment: That is uhmmm not a very good H-bridge... What is your overal goal?

Comment: You need at least 4 switches if you want to reverse the direction of the current if you have one positive rail. If you have a positive and negative rail you need two switches. I have no idea why you posted the picture below with the NPN and PNP. Please change your question and draw a circuit with your intended design. (the circuit editor button)

Comment: The efficiency of the bridge doesn't matter to me I just want to connect the two inputs to the line with the 47 ohm resister with transistors.

Comment: For 3-state output, you need at least 3 possible input states. If you consider the switch in the circuit you just linked in that comment as a *trinary* input (a/b/off), you have that. However, in a *real* digital control circuit, this will require at least 2 input 'wires'/'traces' (tri-state logic devices with high/low/hi-Z outputs are available, but in real circuits the hi-Z state usually just makes a previous state look 'sticky')

Comment: Could you outline a possible schematic if I am driving a 0.4A motor?

Comment: @Goodwin -  " I just want to connect the two inputs to the line with the 47 ohm resister with transistors. " No. No you don't. If you provide enough voltage to turn on the upper transistor, you must also turn on the lower, and this will short-circuit your power supply. Go back to wherever you got your bridge circuit from and look more closely.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I am not even talking about the h-bridge. In order to switch the directly you must send current to one side of the gates to go forward and the other for backwards. In order to be able to switch direction I must setup some transistor switch to switch between them. I was wondering if anyone has a diagram that would outline that.

Comment: @Goodwin ok, 4 of us have now provided answers guessing at your exact needs. Please comment/upvote/accept on them, so we can know if you're satisfied with any/all of them, or at least tell us what we all missed in what you're wanting to accomplish.

Comment: @Goodwin - My point is that you don't know what you need for the H-bridge until you have an H-bridge that has the remotest chance of working - and your bridge does not have the remotest chance of working. So it doesn't matter what the drivers put out. First things first. First the bridge, THEN the drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 555 circuit controls **pulse width** suggesting it is some form of speed control. The H bridge uses 4 x NPN BJTs with the upper BJTs pair acting as emitter followers and the lower pair as switches.

If you invert the output of the 555 and apply the two signals to either side of the bridge you should be able to control both direction and speed. At the mid point (50% cycle) the forward signal exactly cancels out the reverse signal (i.e 'off'). At 10% duty cycle it goes forward 10% and reverse 90% of the time (i.e. net reverse). At 90% duty cycle it goes forward 90% and reverse 10% of the time (i.e. net forward). The high frequency of the pulse stops it hunting backwards and forwards.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat guessing at your exact intent here, so correct me if I'm wrong, but are you envisioning one of these circuits:

[image: H-bridge with make/break add-on]

Here high/low signals on the on/off pin will make/break the circuit to one load terminal, while high/low signals on the fwd/rev pin will reverse the polarity (Vcc/GND) connections to the load terminals.

-----OR-----

[image: alternate implimentation]

Here is a "standard" H bridge where High fwd & Low rev = forward motor; High rev & Low fwd = reverse motor; Low fwd & Low rev = no motor power; High fwd & High rev = short circuit from Vcc to GND (and will likely destroy your transistors).

Answer (score 1):

This circuit is untested.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVU8bJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Q1, 2, 3 and 4 form the H-bridge. D1, 2, 3 and 4 protect the transistors.
- With A1 high Q2 turns on and D5 is pulled low turning on Q4. Motor current flows from left to right.
- With A1 off and A2 on the current flow is the opposite direction.
- You need to make sure that A1 and A2 can't turn on simultaneously.

You may need to play around with the resistor values.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't decipher the question. I've modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnhqqr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the FWD/REV line is high the LEFT side of the H-bridge is driven high for high PWM pulses, and the RIGHT side stays low. When the FWD/REV line is low the RIGHT side of the H-bridge is driven high for high PWM pulses and the LEFT side stays low.

There is a difference between what I've shown and making the output of the H-bridge high impedance. If you make it high impedance the motor will slow naturally with friction. If you drive both sides low (zero PWM duty cycle) the motor is being shorted so it will slow much more quickly. If you want the high-impedance option, you would need to change the H-bridge design to add the new state.

Your H-bridge as drawn will not work- it will burn out the transistors as soon as the input goes high.